# Python- working with files in multiple directories

Tags: python, import, package

I realize this may be considered a duplicate question to some of the other questions out there, but I've spent over an hour now reading through various pages and documentation and still don't understand what's going on here.

I'm trying to work with python files in multiple directories; I have essentially this:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    some_file.py
    some_data.dat
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_some_file.py
```

`test_some_file.py` is run from the command line, as the name implies, intended to run the code contained in `some_file.py`, and needs to import it.  However, I can't seem to do so.

I've tried:

```
from myproject import some_file
```

and also

```
from .. import some_file
```

I did manage to make it run using `sys.path`, but that doens't seem to be the correct way to do things based on what I've read.

Secondly, when I did make it run, using `sys.path`, I got an error that it couldn't find `some_data.dat` which is used by `some_file.py`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perennial question from Python programmers. The issue is that Python doesn't play nicely with scripts that are inside of packages. The situation has improved a bit over the last few releases, but it still doesn't do the right thing a lot of the time.

I think the best answer is to restrict where you run your `test_some_file.py` from, and use the Python interpreter's `-m` parameter. That is, change into the directory above `myproject`, and then run `python -m myproject.tests.test_some_file`. This is the only way that will work without messing around with `sys.path`.

This will allow either of your import lines to work correctly. PEP 8 currently recommends using absolute imports always, so the first version is probably better than the relative version using `..`.

Comment: This helped my first question; is there a reason for the second problem, that some_file.py can no longer find some_data.dat?

Comment: @Retsam: What is your cwd from the module in question?

Comment: @Retsam: some_file.py can find some_file.dat in the directory `os.path.split(__file__)[0]`.

Comment: @martineau: Using `__file__` is a good idea, but you need to use `os.path.dirname` rather than `split`.

Comment: @Blckknght: That would be more succinct, but you `split(hairs)` ;-)

Comment: @Retsam: In a nutshell, relative paths won't work in package files run as `__main__`. You could create a do_test_some_file.py at the same level as mymodule with an `import myproject.tests.test_some_file` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like yours, I add the directory of `some_file.py` to `sys.path` (temporarily).

Code:

```
import sys, os
dirname = os.path.dirname(                 # going up by 1 directory
                   os.path.dirname(        # going up by 2 directories
                            sys.argv[0]))
sys.path.append(dirname)
import some_test
```